# crystal report how to deployee on client server in asp.net .

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

When i deployed my project on client server my crystal report not work . How to deploy crystal report on client server. What i need to do, When i publish my project .

```
 protected void FillOrderByClients(DateTime FromDate,DateTime ToDate,int Accountnumber,int SearchBy,int SigDate)
{
    rptClients.ReportSource = null; 
    int CompanyId = 1;

    string path = Server.MapPath("~/Report/OrdersByClient.rpt");
    reportDocument.Load(path);
    DataSet ds = _activeOrdersService.GetOrderByClientsReport(FromDate, ToDate, Accountnumber, CompanyId, SearchBy, SigDate);
    reportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon
    (myLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID, myLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password, myLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName, myLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName);
    reportDocument.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);
    rptClients.Visible = true;
    rptClients.ReportSource = reportDocument;
    rptClients.DataBind();
    rptClients.RefreshReport();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the crystal reports runtime on the server.

[Here is a link to the SAP downloads page for the version of Crystal included in Visual Studio 2010](http://search.sap.com/notes?id=0001529068&boj=/sap/bc/bsp/spn/scn_bosap/notes.do?access=69765F6D6F64653D3939382669765F7361706E6F7465735F6E756D6265723D30303031353239303638). If you need a different version, search the SAP site (and good luck, it's a pain).

Comment: Actually, the 2010 runtime would probably work with your 2008 reports. I still ave some reports created in 2008 and the run fine. Otherwise, you can search SAP for the version you want.

Comment: Make sure that you are installing the correct version of the runtime, otherwise it will throw some errors which are very difficult to troubleshoot